# Source class "\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Tag\Strategy" for "Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Tag\Strategy\Factory" generation does not exist

Tags: magento2

I just deployed my site on OVH and by launching the command `php bin/magento` to check all the magento namespace I come accross this error.
[image]
I have already tried to delete the folder var / to see if it could make it work but it seems not.

Comment: Try deleting **`generated`** folder in the document root.

Comment: Thanks, but which `generated` folder ?

Comment: you can delete the complete folder, named 'generated' under the document root.

Comment: I found the solution, in fact there were no Strategy class in my vendor so I uploaded it manually and everything is working fine. ^^ But thank you for your time.